# Tratamiento mensaje error

Tags: java, log

Supongamos que tengo las siguientes clases:

TestController.java

```
class TestController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/loadAgents", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public List<Agent> loadAgents() {
    List<Agent> result = null;

    try {
        result = dataBaseService.getAgents();   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logService.error(e.toString())
    }
    
    return result;
 }
```

DataBaseService.java

```
class DataBaseService{
  public List<Agent> getAgents() {
    List<Agent> result = null;

    try {
        //DO SOMETHING
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e)
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

En el log: siempre me aparecera un mensaje algo así:

java.lang.Exception: Ha ocurido el error XXX

¿Como puedo hacer para me diga la linea, cual es el error y no salga java.lang.Exception?

Comment: ¿De qué clase es *logService*? En todo caso, a partir del *e.toString()*, lo que tienes es el valor devuelto por el método *toString()* de Exception; de dónde venga ese String es algo que el *logService* no puede saber.

Comment: puedo readaptar el codigo, simplemente esto es un ejemplo. Lo que quiero evitar es que salga cosa de javalang

Comment: A ver, lo de java.lang.Exception aparece porque lo pone allí el método *toString()* de *Exception*. Si no lo quieres, o general el String de otra forma, o después de llamar a *toString* procesas el resultado para quitar esa parte. No hay más.